# when i tried to accessing message table through an api i am getting an error that the table doesn't exists but it exists in db

Tags: loopback

LOOPBACK:
when i tried to access message table through an api, i am getting an error that the table doesn't exists but it exists in db.
i have used mysql db

Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'careuchoose.message' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/server/server.js:124:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at /root/careuchoose/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'careuchoose.message' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/root/careuchoose/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
    at Socket. (/root/careuchoose/server/server.js:124:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at /root/careuchoose/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

```
  "name": "message",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "sender": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sender_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "recipient_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "room_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "job_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 10000
    },
    "seen": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": 0
    },
    "time": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "first_chat": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sender_profile": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

> datasource.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "host":"localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "***",
    "password": "*****",
    "name": "db",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "insecureAuth": "true"
  },
  "admin_db": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "*****",
    "password": "*****",
    "name": "admin_db",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "insecureAuth": "true"
  }
}
```

Its working in local when i tried this in prod env then it shows these errors

Comment: could you add the code that you have got?

Comment: added message.json file to the issue